# Chart js with SignalR Loop from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, signalr, chart.js

So, I wanted to get a loop to get all the data from a database in SQL Server. However I don't know how to get it since the data looks like this:

```
 var data = {
        labels: ['Apple'],
        datasets: [
                  {
                      label: ["Apples","Bananas"],
                      backgroundColor: "#F29220",
                      borderColor: "#F29220",
                      data: [40,60]
                  }]};
```

How do you get the values in a loop so that I can get the same amount of data inside the "label:[]" and the "data:[]" from the database, such so that the amount of graph follows the amount of data in a database.

Please have mercy because I'm new to both this forum and chartjs. I'm using SignalR too so that I can get the data in realtime.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code are you using to extract the data from the database? javascript can't read a database directly. It can only call a web API. If you've written a web API, please post it. Also post the source table definition.

Comment: You should give more explanations about your database structure. The json output should get the value from your database ?